# containerpilot version 3 with Kong

Tags: kong

Here is Kong with containerpilot version 2, It can start without error
    https://github.com/Kong/docker-kong/tree/master/compose/kong

But when I change version containerpilot to 3.6.1 and convert containerpilot.json5 to match with new argument as below:

```
{
  consul: "consul:8500",
  logging: {
    level: "DEBUG",
    format: "json",
    output: "stdout"
  },
  jobs: [
    {
        name: "kong-8000",
        port: 8000,
        health: {
          exec: "/usr/bin/curl --fail -o /dev/null -s http://localhost:8000/",
          interval: 3,
          ttl: 10
        }
      },
      {
         name: "kong-8443",
         port: 8443,
         health: {
           exec: "/usr/bin/curl --fail -o /dev/null -s https://localhost:8443/ --insecure",
           interval: 5,
           ttl: 10
         }
      },
      {
            name: "kong-8001",
            port: 8001,
            health: {
              exec: "/usr/bin/curl --fail -o /dev/null --fail -s http://localhost:8001/status",
              interval: 5,
              ttl: 10
            }
        },
        {
            name: "kong-8444",
            port: 8444,
            health: {
              exec: "/usr/bin/curl  --fail -o /dev/null -s https://localhost:8444/ --insecure",
              interval: 5,
              ttl: 10
            }
        }

  ]
}
```

Kong can't start, Error detail below

```
{"level":"debug","msg":"loaded config: {\"Discovery\":{},\"LogConfig\":{\"level\":\"DEBUG\",\"format\":\"json\",\"output\":\"stdout\"},\"StopTimeout\":5,\"Jobs\":[{\"Name\":\"kong-8000\",\"Exec\":null,\"Port\":8000,\"Interfaces\":null,\"Tags\":null,\"ConsulExtras\":null,\"Health\":{\"CheckExec\":\"/usr/bin/curl --fail -o /dev/null -s http://localhost:
8000/\",\"CheckTimeout\":\"\",\"Heartbeat\":3,\"TTL\":10,\"Logging\":null},\"ExecTimeout\":\"\",\"Restarts\":null,\"StopTimeout\":\"\",\"When\":{\"Frequency\":\"\",\"Source\":\"\",\"Once\":\"\",\"Each\":\"\",\"Timeout\":\"\"},\"Logging\":null},{\"Name\":\"kong-8443\",\"Exec\":null,\"Port\":8443,\"Interfaces\":null,\"Tags\":null,\"ConsulExtras\":null,\
"Health\":{\"CheckExec\":\"/usr/bin/curl --fail -o /dev/null -s https://localhost:8443/ --insecure\",\"CheckTimeout\":\"\",\"Heartbeat\":5,\"TTL\":10,\"Logging\":null},\"ExecTimeout\":\"\",\"Restarts\":null,\"StopTimeout\":\"\",\"When\":{\"Frequency\":\"\",\"Source\":\"\",\"Once\":\"\",\"Each\":\"\",\"Timeout\":\"\"},\"Logging\":null},{\"Name\":\"kong
-8001\",\"Exec\":null,\"Port\":8001,\"Interfaces\":null,\"Tags\":null,\"ConsulExtras\":null,\"Health\":{\"CheckExec\":\"/usr/bin/curl --fail -o /dev/null --fail -s http://localhost:8001/status\",\"CheckTimeout\":\"\",\"Heartbeat\":5,\"TTL\":10,\"Logging\":null},\"ExecTimeout\":\"\",\"Restarts\":null,\"StopTimeout\":\"\",\"When\":{\"Frequency\":\"\",\"
Source\":\"\",\"Once\":\"\",\"Each\":\"\",\"Timeout\":\"\"},\"Logging\":null},{\"Name\":\"kong-8444\",\"Exec\":null,\"Port\":8444,\"Interfaces\":null,\"Tags\":null,\"ConsulExtras\":null,\"Health\":{\"CheckExec\":\"/usr/bin/curl  --fail -o /dev/null -s https://localhost:8444/ --insecure\",\"CheckTimeout\":\"\",\"Heartbeat\":5,\"TTL\":10,\"Logging\":nul
l},\"ExecTimeout\":\"\",\"Restarts\":null,\"StopTimeout\":\"\",\"When\":{\"Frequency\":\"\",\"Source\":\"\",\"Once\":\"\",\"Each\":\"\",\"Timeout\":\"\"},\"Logging\":null}],\"Watches\":null,\"Telemetry\":null,\"Control\":{\"SocketPath\":\"/var/run/containerpilot.socket\"}}","time":"2017-12-29T16:46:07Z"}
{"level":"debug","msg":"control: initialized router for control server","time":"2017-12-29T16:46:07Z"}
{"level":"debug","msg":"control: listening to /var/run/containerpilot.socket","time":"2017-12-29T16:46:07Z"}
{"level":"debug","msg":"event: {Startup global}","time":"2017-12-29T16:46:07Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"control: serving at /var/run/containerpilot.socket","time":"2017-12-29T16:46:07Z"}
{"level":"debug","msg":"timer: {TimerExpired kong-8000.heartbeat}","time":"2017-12-29T16:46:10Z"}
{"level":"debug","msg":"check.kong-8000.Run start","time":"2017-12-29T16:46:10Z"}
{"level":"error","msg":"check.kong-8000 exited with error: exit status 7","time":"2017-12-29T16:46:10Z"}
{"level":"debug","msg":"event: {ExitFailed check.kong-8000}","time":"2017-12-29T16:46:10Z"}
{"level":"debug","msg":"event: {Error check.kong-8000: exit status 7}","time":"2017-12-29T16:46:10Z"}
{"level":"debug","msg":"check.kong-8000.Run end","time":"2017-12-29T16:46:10Z"}
{"level":"debug","msg":"check.kong-8000.term","time":"2017-12-29T16:46:10Z"}
{"level":"debug","msg":"terminating command 'check.kong-8000' at pid: 15","time":"2017-12-29T16:46:10Z"}
{"level":"debug","msg":"event: {StatusUnhealthy kong-8000}","time":"2017-12-29T16:46:10Z"}
{"level":"debug","msg":"timer: {TimerExpired kong-8444.heartbeat}","time":"2017-12-29T16:46:12Z"}
```

Please help